# Can two apps use camera at the same time in android phone?

Tags: android

Or is it impossible no matter how you build or code apps?

I am saying in android version 5.0
Which was released 2014-2016.

I mean if when one app is using camera in “background” , is using another camera app at the same time possible??

Some people say it depends on how the applications is coded.

Also the app “sound assistant” makes 2 music apps using speaker at the same time.
Then how about camera???

And i saw a comment saying

“Our current frame work does support limited support for multi-app access to the camera.
We allow one (and only one) "controlling" app to the camera, but an arbitrary number of "shared" apps to access the same camera.
There are some limitations for "shared" apps:

1. No camera controls Exposure/White
   Balance/Focus, etc...).
2. No media type selection (can't choose VGA vs.
   720p vS. 1080p, etc...).
3. Only access to a video stream by default, photo pins are blocked (any photo operation will use a video frame instead).
   The "controlling" app decides what media type to use and can set any camera control. Any of the sharing app can register to be notified if a controlling app releases control of the camera, at which point, the sharing app can re-open the camera in controlling mode.
   The mechanism described above does not require any copying of the captured frame so the overhead is minimal.”

What this comment means? does it say 2apps can access to camera at the sametime anyway in android??

Any way thanks for reading  and I want to know if the phone is rooted , this can be possible

thank you for reading !

Comment: Cross-posted to Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249263/44325

Comment: Re: "*“Our current frame work [...]*", looks like it's copied from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/WINDOWS/en-US/12de4147-9fa0-4031-818f-2cec9a1d080b/access-camera-from-multiple-application-at-the-same-time?forum=wdk which is about Windows?